# Web Performance Test in Cloud Load Test sends cookie on some tests

Tags: visual-studio-2013, performance-testing, load-testing, azure-devops

I have a web performance test that begins with a webforms login, executes a few steps and then finishes.

Mostly this runs without errors but if I extend the load test run beyond 15 minutes I start to get load test failures which fail because some tests send a Session and Auth cookie on the initial Get to the root url.

Clearly the test recording does not have cookies on the initial request. Additionally, I have set the "Percentage of New Users" on the scenarios to 100% to ensure that all tests are running as a new user.

The test is databound to a list of 600 users in a User Pace scenario. Nothing very heavy.

However, I cannot identify why after a period of time (12 minutes) some of the tests begin to send the cookies on the initial request!

Can anyone give me any pointers please?

Comment: I might have found the cause of this. I have been using a User Pace load strategy and there appears to be a correlation between what would be the calculated test start times and the number of times a test is repeated for a User (in this case 4 per user). Therefore, the second test for a user is started with the session cookie from the earlier test (we had to assume a user will not log out for our scripting). This means that the 100% New Users setting is not being observed in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question and on re-reading it not very clear.

The scenario reflects more my lack of knowledge of the web testing features I was using.

I am fairly certain it was caused by a missing "log out" test step combined with the configuration of the load test probably re-using connections.

After much prodding around I achieved some clean runs